# Can't apply textRotation in Google Sheets API?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I am creating a script in python which will generate me a spreadsheet which I need.

The problem is, when I add rotation and formatting in this order

```
            # Set labels angle in top row of each Unit table
            'repeatCell': {
                'cell': {
                    'userEnteredFormat': {
                        'textRotation': { 'angle': 45 }
                        }
                    },
                'fields': '*',
                'range': {
                    'sheetId': index,
                    'startRowIndex': 0,
                    'endRowIndex': 1,
                    'startColumnIndex': 3,  # Duration
                    'endColumnIndex': 24    # Hours
                    }
                }
            }, {

           # Set formatting for each Unit table
            'repeatCell': {
                'cell': {
                    'userEnteredFormat': {
                        'horizontalAlignment': 'CENTER',
                        'verticalAlignment': 'MIDDLE',
                        'wrapStrategy': 'WRAP',
                        'textFormat': {
                            'fontFamily': 'arial',
                            'fontSize': 10,
                            'bold': True
                            },
                        'borders': {
                            'top': { 'style': 'SOLID' },
                            'bottom': { 'style': 'SOLID' },
                            'left': { 'style': 'SOLID' },
                            'right': { 'style': 'SOLID' }
                            }
                        }
                    },
                'fields': '*',
                'range': { 'sheetId': index }
                }
```

I don't get the rotation.

But if I change the order, then I get the text rotation, but I lose borders and all the other formatting.

Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I saw your request body, I thought that the reason for your current issue is due to that you are using `*` as `fields`. In this case, all properties are changed. So, in your situation, please restrict the properties using `fields`

When your request body is modified, it becomes as follows.

#### Modified request body:

```json
{
  "requests": [
    {
      "repeatCell": {
        "cell": {
          "userEnteredFormat": {
            "textRotation": {
              "angle": 45
            }
          }
        },
        "fields": "userEnteredFormat.textRotation",
        "range": {
          "sheetId": index,
          "startRowIndex": 0,
          "endRowIndex": 1,
          "startColumnIndex": 3,
          "endColumnIndex": 24
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "repeatCell": {
        "cell": {
          "userEnteredFormat": {
            "horizontalAlignment": "CENTER",
            "verticalAlignment": "MIDDLE",
            "wrapStrategy": "WRAP",
            "textFormat": {
              "fontFamily": "arial",
              "fontSize": 10,
              "bold": true
            },
            "borders": {
              "top": {
                "style": "SOLID"
              },
              "bottom": {
                "style": "SOLID"
              },
              "left": {
                "style": "SOLID"
              },
              "right": {
                "style": "SOLID"
              }
            }
          }
        },
        "fields": "userEnteredFormat(horizontalAlignment,verticalAlignment,wrapStrategy,textFormat,borders)",
        "range": {
          "sheetId": index
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

- In this case, `userEnteredFormat.textRotation` and `userEnteredFormat(horizontalAlignment,verticalAlignment,wrapStrategy,textFormat,borders)` are used to 1st and 2nd requests, respectively.
- For example, at the 1st request, when you want to clear another format in your range, please use `*`.

#### Reference:

- [RepeatCellRequest](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/request#repeatcellrequest)